# Call data after refreshing the page (React Native Hooks)

Tags: react-hooks, react-native

Here's my code first

```js
const [getData, setGetData] = useState();
const [ref, setRef] = useState();

const initializeData = async() => {
  const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user_id');
  setGetData(JSON.parse(userToken));
}

useEffect(() => {
  return initializeData();
},[])

useEffect(() => {
  let interval;
  if(getData != null)
  {
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      setRef(firestore().collection('**********').where("SendersNo", "==", getData.number));
    }, 2000);
  }
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
},[getData])

useEffect(() => {

  if(ref != null)
  {
    return ref.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
      const list = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          const {
              id,driverName,driverContactNumber,driverRating,driverPlateNumber,driverTrackingNumber,userPlaceName,
              destinationPlaceName,PaymentMethod,Fare
          } = doc.data();
          list.push({id: doc.id,driverName,driverContactNumber,driverRating,
            driverPlateNumber,driverTrackingNumber,userPlaceName,destinationPlaceName,PaymentMethod,Fare});
      });
      setUserBookingData(list);
      console.log("HEY!");
    });
  }
  
},[])

const CurrentTransaction = () => {
  if(ref == null)
  {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>You don't have a Current Transaction</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
  else
  {
    return userBookingData.map((element) => {
      return (
        <View key={element.id}>
             <View>
                 <Text>{element.name}</Text>
             </View>
        </View>
         )
        });
     }
}
```

So currently right now what I am trying to is if there's a data on my firestore it will update on the screen but before updating it I need to get the data from the `setGetData` so that I can query it but the problem is that when I refresh the whole simulator/page it doesn't get the data but instead just a blank page . But when i edit and save my code without refreshing the page/simulator it can get the data . Can someone help me what I am doing wrong .

EDIT

if I do this

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if(ref != null)
  {
    return ref.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
      const list = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          const {
              id,driverName,driverContactNumber,driverRating,driverPlateNumber,driverTrackingNumber,userPlaceName,
              destinationPlaceName,PaymentMethod,Fare
          } = doc.data();
          list.push({id: doc.id,driverName,driverContactNumber,driverRating,
            driverPlateNumber,driverTrackingNumber,userPlaceName,destinationPlaceName,PaymentMethod,Fare});
      });
      setUserBookingData(list);
      console.log("HEY!");
    });
  }
  else
  {
    return null;
  }
},[ref])
```

it keeps looping the `console.log('hey')` but it can get the data and display it . but it loops so its bad.

Comment: where is the ref variable come ?

Comment: @ucup I edit my question . it's a state

Comment: oh so the ref is not exist yet

Comment: yes i need to set it yet to have a query in firestore

Comment: the reason why its infinity loop its because you put set interval on setRef. and you put [ref] on the other useeffect. so everytime the value of ref is updated the second useeffect will also trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i believe snapshot from firebase realtime database is a listener so its doesn't need setinterval

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if(getData != null)
  {
    const ref = firestore().collection('**********').where("SendersNo", "==", getData.number);
    ref.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
      const list = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          const {
              id,driverName,driverContactNumber,driverRating,driverPlateNumber,driverTrackingNumber,userPlaceName,
              destinationPlaceName,PaymentMethod,Fare
          } = doc.data();
          list.push({id: doc.id,driverName,driverContactNumber,driverRating,
            driverPlateNumber,driverTrackingNumber,userPlaceName,destinationPlaceName,PaymentMethod,Fare});
      });
      setUserBookingData(list);
      console.log("HEY!");
    });

  }
  return () => {
   //clear your ref listener here
  }
},[getData])
```

if you put a return on use effect it will be called after the screen is no longer used.

```js
useEffect(()=>{
  //inside this will be called when the screen complete render
  const someListener = DeviceEventEmitter('listentosomething',()=>{
  //do something
  });
return ()=>{
 //inside this will be called after the screen no longer be used 
 //example go to other screen
someListener.remove();
}
},)
```

Comment: Let me check on this DeviceEventEmitter. Thank you ucup

Comment: ahh I understand now . The example above won't work without the dependency and return on the `useEffect`

Comment: please check my edit question . Thank you ucup

Comment: it was becaause of the interval